# Why does a the ignite client open a port?

Tags: ignite

We have started using Apache Ignite and we are using TCP-communication. What we are seeing is that the clients are opening a port for communication just like the server. 
My first assumption was that we don't need to open up from the server to the client, everything seemed to be working fine. However, in some cases when the topology is changing we got stack traces in the logs that indicates that the server is initiating communication with the client on this port and fails.

My question is why is the server trying to communicate directly with the client? Do we need to let the servers communicate with the client or can we simply ignore the error messages?

Below is an example of the stack trace:

```
    2016-07-04 16:02:32,298 ERROR [marshaller-cache-#67%PMCacheCluster%] [org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.continuous.CacheContinuousQueryHandler]  [NONE] - Failed to send event notification to node: ad8937b4-eb38-442a-8e06-9625c6246d7b

    org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to send message (node may have left the grid or TCP connection cannot be established due to firewall issues) [node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=ad8937b4-eb38-442a-8e06-9625c6246d7b, addrs=[xxx.xx.x.xxx], sockAddrs=[/xxx.xx.x.xxx:0, /xxx.xx.x.xxx:0], discPort=0, order=51, intOrder=29, lastExchangeTime=1467640045240, loc=false, ver=1.6.0#20160518-sha1:0b22c45b, isClient=true], topic=T4 [topic=TOPIC_CACHE, id1=ee261127-933b-36b7-b4ef-f5be9bb4bff2, id2=ad8937b4-eb38-442a-8e06-9625c6246d7b, id3=0], msg=GridContinuousMessage [type=MSG_EVT_NOTIFICATION, routineId=7107ffc5-9868-422f-8509-4739558869f7, data=null, futId=null], policy=2]
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.send(GridIoManager.java:1290)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.sendOrderedMessage(GridIoManager.java:1508)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.continuous.GridContinuousProcessor.sendWithRetries(GridContinuousProcessor.java:1229)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.continuous.GridContinuousProcessor.sendWithRetries(GridContinuousProcessor.java:1200)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.continuous.GridContinuousProcessor.sendWithRetries(GridContinuousProcessor.java:1182)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.continuous.GridContinuousProcessor.sendNotification(GridContinuousProcessor.java:843)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.continuous.GridContinuousProcessor.addNotification(GridContinuousProcessor.java:802)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.continuous.CacheContinuousQueryHandler.onEntryUpdate(CacheContinuousQueryHandler.java:787)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.continuous.CacheContinuousQueryHandler.access$700(CacheContinuousQueryHandler.java:91)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.continuous.CacheContinuousQueryHandler$1.onEntryUpdated(CacheContinuousQueryHandler.java:412)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.continuous.CacheContinuousQueryManager.onEntryUpdated(CacheContinuousQueryManager.java:343)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheMapEntry.innerUpdate(GridCacheMapEntry.java:2522)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.updateSingle(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:2246)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.updateAllAsyncInternal0(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:1644)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.updateAllAsyncInternal(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:1484)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.processNearAtomicUpdateRequest(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:2940)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.access$600(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:129)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache$5.apply(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:260)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache$5.apply(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:258)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.processMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:622)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.onMessage0(GridCacheIoManager.java:320)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.handleMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:244)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.access$000(GridCacheIoManager.java:81)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager$1.onMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:203)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.invokeListener(GridIoManager.java:1219)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.processRegularMessage0(GridIoManager.java:847)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$1700(GridIoManager.java:105)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$5.run(GridIoManager.java:810)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Failed to send message to remote node: TcpDiscoveryNode [id=ad8937b4-eb38-442a-8e06-9625c6246d7b, addrs=[xxx.xx.x.xxx], sockAddrs=[/xxx.xx.x.xxx:0, /xxx.xx.x.xxx:0], discPort=0, order=51, intOrder=29, lastExchangeTime=1467640045240, loc=false, ver=1.6.0#20160518-sha1:0b22c45b, isClient=true]
            at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.sendMessage0(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:1993)
            at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.sendMessage(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:1933)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.send(GridIoManager.java:1285)
            ... 30 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to connect to node (is node still alive?). Make sure that each ComputeTask and GridCacheTransaction has a timeout set in order to prevent parties from waiting forever in case of network issues [nodeId=ad8937b4-eb38-442a-8e06-9625c6246d7b, addrs=[/xxx.xx.x.xxx:47100, /xxx.xx.x.xxx:47100]]
            at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createTcpClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:2496)
            at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createNioClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:2137)
            at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.reserveClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:2031)
            at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.sendMessage0(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:1967)
            ... 32 common frames omitted
            Suppressed: org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to connect to address: /xxx.xx.x.xxx:47100
                    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createTcpClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:2501)
                    ... 35 common frames omitted
            Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
                    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
                    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
                    at sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor.connect(SocketAdaptor.java:111)
                    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createTcpClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:2360)
                    ... 35 common frames omitted
            Suppressed: org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to connect to address: /xxx.xx.x.xxx:47100
                    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createTcpClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:2501)
                    ... 35 common frames omitted
            Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
                    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
                    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
                    at sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor.connect(SocketAdaptor.java:111)
                    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createTcpClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:2360)
                    ... 35 common frames omitted

    2016-07-04 16:02:34,923 ERROR [marshaller-cache-#67%PMCacheCluster%] [org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.continuous.CacheContinuousQueryHandler]  [NONE] - Failed to send event notification to node: 95d9812d-4a16-4589-93a8-0bf2aa6b8413
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client nodes are different from server nodes mostly by the fact that they don't hold cache data and don't execute computations.

Other than that, client nodes are first-class cluster citizens and participate in communications the same way as servers do. So yes, they need to accept connections.

See https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/clients-vs-servers